# Fetch multiple rows in join (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I am having trouble getting the results that I am expecting from the code below.

First Step is:

Fetch one row from a table an join multiple rows from another table... the rsult array should look like this:

```
array(
  field_1, 
  field_2, 
  field_3, 
  joined_array(
    field_a_array(
      field_a_a, 
      field_a_b, 
      field_a_c
    ), 
    field_b_array(
      field_b_a, 
      field_b_b, 
      field_b_c
    )
  ) 
)
```

My query looks something like this:

(it seems that the position of where, join, etc isnt important for the codigniters db class)

```
$this->db->select('events.*, genres_x_events.*');

$this->db->from('events');
$this->db->where('events.slug', $slug);
$this->db->where('events.deleted', 0);

$this->db->join('genres_x_events', 'genres_x_events.event_slug = events.slug');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

The issue that I'm facing is that I am only getting one row from the join when I am expecting to retrieve multiple rows per join.

EDIT:

last_query():

```
SELECT `events`.*, `genres_x_events`.`genre_slug`
FROM (`events`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres_x_events` ON `genres_x_events`.`event_slug` = `events`.`slug`
WHERE `events`.`slug` =  'test'
AND `events`.`deleted` =  0
```

output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [headline] => test
            [subheadline] => 
            [slug] => test
            [date] => 2012-08-10
            [start_time] => 00:00:00
            [end_time] => 00:00:00
            [price] => 
            [body] => 
            [location_id] => 5
            [genre_id] => 0
            [creation_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:33
            [update_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:41
            [deleted] => 0
            [genre_slug] => rock
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [headline] => test
            [subheadline] => 
            [slug] => test
            [date] => 2012-08-10
            [start_time] => 00:00:00
            [end_time] => 00:00:00
            [price] => 
            [body] => 
            [location_id] => 5
            [genre_id] => 0
            [creation_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:33
            [update_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:41
            [deleted] => 0
            [genre_slug] => metal
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [headline] => test
            [subheadline] => 
            [slug] => test
            [date] => 2012-08-10
            [start_time] => 00:00:00
            [end_time] => 00:00:00
            [price] => 
            [body] => 
            [location_id] => 5
            [genre_id] => 0
            [creation_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:33
            [update_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:41
            [deleted] => 0
            [genre_slug] => indie
        )

)
```

would like output (something like that would be cool):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [headline] => test
            [subheadline] => 
            [slug] => test
            [date] => 2012-08-10
            [start_time] => 00:00:00
            [end_time] => 00:00:00
            [price] => 
            [body] => 
            [location_id] => 5
            [genre_id] => 0
            [creation_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:33
            [update_date] => 2012-08-10 14:26:41
            [deleted] => 0
            [genres] => Array(
                [0] => rock
                [1] => metal
                [2] => indie
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: have you tried running a sql statement that you've constructed against the db server? based on your CI code i'm assuming it's something like `select * from events e join genres_x_events g on e.slug = g.event_slug where e.deleted = 0 and e.slug = 'SOMEVALUEHERE';`

Comment: The output of `$this->db->last_query();` would be helpful.

Comment: Yes. Please post your **actual** output and then give us an idea of what you're **expected** output would be.

Comment: i have updated the inital post with the last query, the output, and my desired output ;)

Comment: You will need to use an ORM like doctrine.

Comment: So you're getting the correct data, but it's not in a PHP structure that you want it to be. I have a feeling that the best approach will be to iterate your result set and work it into the structure that you'd like it to be.

Comment: hm, i feared that ... is there no way to do it in one querry?

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping it by the event.id and then use group_concat, something like this:

```
SELECT `events`.*, group_concat(`genres_x_events`.`genre_slug`)
FROM (`events`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres_x_events` ON `genres_x_events`.`event_slug` = `events`.`slug`
WHERE `events`.`slug` =  'test'
AND `events`.`deleted` =  0
GROUP BY events.id
```

This will give you a comma separated list of all genres for a given event.id. You can change the delimiter(to something like a pipe) by using something like this

```
SELECT `events`.*, group_concat(`genres_x_events`.`genre_slug` SEPARATOR '|')
FROM (`events`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres_x_events` ON `genres_x_events`.`event_slug` = `events`.`slug`
WHERE `events`.`slug` =  'test'
AND `events`.`deleted` =  0
GROUP BY events.id
```